# Extending the Session Library in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I've been using CI for a while now and recently upgraded to CI 3. I noticed the Session library has now been moved to a folder.
I used to have my own MY_Session.php file in the application/libraries folder that extended the default CI library.

I also use the autoload.php file to autoload my session library.
This no longer works, as I get Unable to load the requested class: Session.

If I remove MY_Session.php file, then the pages load, but then I'll be missing my extended functionality.

Does anyone know how exactly to extend the session library in CI 3?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by CodeIgniter 3?  Their website states the latest version is `2.1.3`

Comment: the nightly build, or CodeIgniter reactor, as they refer to it.
[https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter)

Comment: Do you receive any errors? That could help us identify the problem.

Comment: yes. I get the usual CI error that says : Unable to load the requested class: Session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently it is impossible to do that, but there's a [pending pull request](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/1787) that tries to solve the problem.

However, you shouldn't post questions related to yet unreleased software. Anything that is in a *development* stage might be changed again, become obsolete, etc. and your question here would automatically become irrelevant to everybody, including yourself. You should post/ask your questions on the repository itself (and search for an already existing issue of course).

Comment: It is possible to extend the session class of CodeIgniter 3. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300283/extending-the-session-library-in-codeigniter-3/14965340#14965340

Comment: @c.hill It wasn't possible at the time the question was asked (and when I answered it). After all (and as I noted), CodeIgniter 3 is still in development.

Answer (score 13):

For the sake of completeness since 3.0 has long been released: if you want to extend the Session class, you need to add your extended class MY_Session.php to the application/libraries/Session directory to mimic its system/libraries/Session/Session.php counterpart.

After you have the correct directory structure, your MY_Session.php file should contain the usual way to extend system library classes, as @Starx has noted.

Answer (score 2):

It **is** possible to extend the Session class in CodeIgniter 3. Admittedly it is a bit of a kludge, but I only use this to fix a long-standing bug in the Session class anyways. Here is an example **MY_Session.php** library for CI3:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once SYSDIR . '/libraries/Driver.php';
require_once SYSDIR . '/libraries/Session/Session.php';

/*
    Change the following if you want to use a different driver.
*/
require_once SYSDIR . '/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_cookie.php';

class MY_Session extends CI_Session_cookie
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function _sess_update($force = false)
    {
        // Do NOT update an existing session on AJAX calls.
        if ($force || !$this->CI->input->is_ajax_request())
            return parent::_sess_update($force);
    }

}

/* End of file MY_Session.php */
/* Location: ./application/libraries/MY_Session.php */
```

For more info, or to keep up with this if it changes:
http://degreesofzero.com/article/55

Disclosure: This is my personal blog.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to extend CI_Session in Codeigniter 3.1.3. Here is what I did:

Create a file application/libraries/Session/MY_Session.php

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                           
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Session extends CI_Session {

    public function __construct(array $params = array())
    {   
        if ( $this->ignore_sessions() )
            return;
        parent::__construct();
    }   

    function ignore_sessions()
    {   
        $uri = str_replace ("//", "/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        if ( strpos($uri, '/ignore_this_controller/') === 0 ) 
            return true;
        return false;
    }   
}
```

You might also want to add 'session' to your config/autoload.php:

$autoload['libraries'] = array('session',....)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this similar to extending other core components.

```
class MY_Session extends CI_Session {

    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo "In extended the session";
    }
}
```

Make sure you load the session library as well. Like

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

Also, `Unable to load the requested class: Session` are generally triggered for the two reasons.

- CI can't fine the session
- You haven't autoloaded the library

Also, make sure you have a encryption key on your `config.php`

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

Comment: I already had this. This doesn't work. I mentioned that in the original question.

Comment: yes. I have all of these in place. I still get the same error. Where would you put MY_Session.php? I have it in applications/libraries folder

Comment: @luv2Code, That would be the right place to do it. Are you on linux system?

Comment: yes Linux. I can extend any other library no problem but this one is messed up because they moved it to a folder

Answer (score -1):

I hope is not to late :

When you load (or autoload) the Session library, you must now load it as a driver instead of a library. This means calling

```
$this->load->driver('session')
```

instead of

`$this->load->library('session')`

and/or listing ‘session’ in

`$autoload['drivers']`

instead of

`$autoload['libraries']`